# Ubuntu upgrade multiple versions at once

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, apt, upgrade

I need an Ubuntu 11.10 server, but for reasons beyond my understanding, our host only preinstalls Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. So I decided to get a 10.04 server and use Ubuntu's do-release-upgrade to get to 11.10.

I expected that do-release-upgrade would get me straight from 10.04 to 11.10. However, after running do-release-upgrade, I ended up with Ubuntu 10.10. So after reboot I had to run it again, and then it upgraded to 11.04, so then I had to run it a third time to get to 11.10. Is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Canonical only supports one major version prior to the current version (outside of LTS support).  So it would make sense that the only upgrade path to receive any QA attention would be from the last prior release to the next.  So with no documentation in front of me, I suggest that this is expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes:

> To avoid damaging your running system, upgrading should only be done
>   from one release to the next release (e.g. Ubuntu 9.04 to Ubuntu 9.10)
>   or from one LTS release to the next (e.g. Ubuntu 6.06 LTS to Ubuntu
>   8.04 LTS). If you wish to 'skip' a version, you can backup your data and do a fresh installation, or progressively upgrade to each
>   successive version. For example, to upgrade from Ubuntu 8.10 to Ubuntu
>   9.10, first upgrade to 9.04, then upgrade 9.04 to 9.10.